# pipe and grep in Docker container seems to get blocked

Tags: bash, docker, grep

I have a simple bash script as follows that is part of a docker image.

`test.sh`,

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

logit() {
    log_date=`date +"%F %T"`
    echo "[$log_date][INFO] $1"
}

waitForServerToStart() {
    while true; do
        logit "Testing .... 1"
        netstat -anpt
        logit "Testing .... 2"
        netstat -anpt | grep tcp
        logit "Testing .... 3"
        sleep 5
        logit "Testing .... 4"
    done
}

waitForServerToStart
```

`run.sh`,

```
#!/bin/sh

/test.sh &

# Run forever
while true; do sleep 5; done
```

Dockerfile,

```
FROM openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.9

COPY files/run.sh /
COPY files/test.sh /

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

If I run this container I only get the following output which leads me to believe somehow `grep` and "pipe" seem to get blocked.

```
[2019-03-06 11:10:45][INFO] Testing .... 1
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:58278        xxx.xxx.xx.xx:443     FIN_WAIT2   -
[2019-03-06 11:10:45][INFO] Testing .... 2
```

Can someone please shed some light around this ?

It works fine If I comment out `netstat -anpt | grep tcp`. I would then see the subsequent log lines and it would also continue in the loop.

```
[2019-03-06 11:25:36][INFO] Testing .... 3
[2019-03-06 11:25:41][INFO] Testing .... 4
```

Comment: Can you give more logs, I ran the program on my machine, it seems to work fine. I want to compare what is there that you are not seeing on your console.

Comment: Your `run.sh` script launches a background process and then exits.  Since that script is the main container process, once it exits, the container exits too.

Comment: @DavidMaze added a bit more information in the description

Comment: @DavidMaze also i forgot to mention `run.sh` has few other things like running a elasticsearch instance with `exec su-exec elasticsearch /bin/elasticsearch`. So `run.sh` should never `exit 0`

Comment: @vancleff check the description. will give you a more repeatable test now.

Comment: I ran a container using this image `openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine3.9` and it seems `grep` is there and working fine. This is some other issue. Can you explain what you're intending to do with netstat ?

Comment: it definitely blocks for me with `netstat`. anyway the intention was to pull the container ip. `netstat` is one of several ways. theres ofc looking at `/etc/hosts` and may be using `ip` cmd as well. but i more curious why `netstat` to grep gets blocked in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one has me puzzled! But I have a solution for you:

Use awk instead of grep

In `test.sh` use this instead:

```
netstat -anpt | awk /tcp/
```

So that the file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

logit() {
    log_date=`date +"%F %T"`
    echo "[$log_date][INFO] $1"
}

waitForServerToStart() {
    while true; do
        logit "Testing .... 1"
        netstat -anpt
        logit "Testing .... 2"
        netstat -anpt | awk /tcp/
        logit "Testing .... 3"
        sleep 5
        logit "Testing .... 4"
    done
}

waitForServerToStart
```

For a reason that I cannot explain - `grep` will not return when reading from the pipe when invoked from the script. I created your container locally, ran it and entered it - and the command `netstat -anpt | grep tcp` runs just fine and exits. If you replace it with `netstat -anpt | cat` in your `test.sh` script, then it will also pass just fine.

I looked all over the place for the someone with an identical issue with grep in a container from the distro you are using, the version etc. - but came up empty handed.

I believe that it may have to do with grep waiting for a EOF character that never lands - but I am not sure.

Comment: yeah what i thought about the EOF as well. Its strange that no one else has discovered this issue.

Comment: @Andrews i have marked your address. the main purpose of this grep was I wanted to pull the ip from inside the docker container. Theres number of ways to do it i know. But i was more curious about this problem than anything.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that I couldn't make the answer work with grep. I sure am wondering too, how noone else apparently has seen this issue.